# Magic Mouse inertial scrolling and multi-touch gestures

Tags: trackpad, touchegg

Is it possible to use inertial two finger scrolling on Ubuntu with a magic mouse and also set up 3 finger swipes to trigger actions in compiz?

Maybe using touchegg?
I know it's possible with the Magic Trackpad but what about more than normal mouse usage for the Magic Mouse?
Thanks!

Comment: Some of what your mentioning should be available in precise. There have been new multitouch x drivers, kernel updates and other developments surrounding this form of hardware.

Comment: regarding the two-finger scrolling, look at the 'Mouse and Touchpad' settings in 'system settings'. In the touchpad tab you should have the option two enable 2finger scrolling. forthe other function I think you need touchegg. But I've never been able to figure it out

Comment: This question is quite old, and has no accepted answer. If this question no longer applies then please consider deleting it or answering it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I have not found an answer. Why should open questions be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

This?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleMagicMouse

Comment: This doesn't provide inertial scrolling. (Doesn't work for me)